# Unable to see application console logs in azure log stream, filesystem , blob storage

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-diagnostics, azure-appservice

We are using spring boot app deployed in azure app service , App is using Logback by default and logging in console. Even though i have configured the storageV2 account to retreive the logs in blob storage , enabled to store logs in filesystem still i am not able to see the logs at any place. Is there any further configuration needed to be added in java app to get the logs ? Though i am getting web server related logs (url getting hit) but
app logs are not showing up.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you configure it on Azure Portal?

Comment: @JimXu I am logging it in console using logback framework , and in azure portal in the app service logs present in app service resource i have started filesystem logging, blob storage (app log and webserver log). After this i am looking at 1) log stream present at portal and 2) blob storage files,  but can only see the webserver logs (request hit) but no app logs.